# How to bring a subview to the front when you tap it?

Tags: ios

I have a view with about 30 subviews on it.  I want to add code in my subview's viewcontroller so that when I tap the subview, the subview expands to fill the screen.

I'm using `[self.view setFrame:rect]` to expand the subview, and this works fine.  The problem is that some of the other 29 subviews are above the subview that I just tapped, so they're still visible.

I've tried using `bringSubviewToFront` from the parent viewcontroller, but this appears to have no effect.  Is there any code I can put in my subview's viewcontroller class to make this happen?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

bringSubviewToFront should work, just make sure you're using it correctly. The usage is.

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:childView];
```

Comment: And to expand on this answer a bit, this bit of code works from the `UIView` itself: `[self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];`.

Comment: I would nitpick the answer to `[childView.superview bringSubviewToFront:childView];` so that it's not necessary to "have" the superview already referenced.

Answer (score 12):

Use this code, even you don't know about superView:

**In objective-c:**

```
[subview.superview bringSubviewToFront: subview];
```

**In swift:**

```
subview.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: subview)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the ease of use an extension in **Swift 3**

```
extension UIView {

    func bringToFront() {
        self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Objective-C:**

```
[self.superview bringSubviewToFront: subview];
```

**In Swift 2.3:**

```
self.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(subview)
```

**In Swift 3.1.1 - Swift 4.1:**

```
superview.bringSubview(toFront: subview)
```