# C4 wondering about the drawing order

Tags: objective-c, c4

I've been creating a couple of shapes, labels,... on top of each other. sometimes they are displayed as expected (whatever is added later will appear on top) but sometimes it doesn't..
I've been adding the exact same code to 2 different subviews and it results in different display orders of the single items.

using the zPosition property also doesn't help at all...
What might be happening?

EDIT CODE ADDED:
this is the function I'm running in my subclass:

```
-(void)topBarSetup{
    //--------------------------------------------------
    //underlying rect
    //--------------------------------------------------
    topNavBar=[C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(0, topBarFromTop, self.canvas.width, topBarHeight)];
    topNavBar.fillColor=navBarColor;
    topNavBar.lineWidth=0;
    [self.canvas addShape:topNavBar];

    //center label
    titleLabel = [C4Label labelWithText:@"Add Photo Letter" font:fatFont];
    titleLabel.center=topNavBar.center;
    [self.canvas addLabel:titleLabel];

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //LEFT
    //--------------------------------------------------
    //back text
    backLabel=[C4Label labelWithText:@"Back" font: normalFont];
    backLabel.center=CGPointMake(40, topNavBar.center.y);
    [self.canvas addLabel:backLabel];

    //back icon
    //backButtonImage=iconBack;
    backButtonImage.width= 12.2;
    backButtonImage.center=CGPointMake(10, topNavBar.center.y);
    [self.canvas addImage:backButtonImage];

    //invisible rect to interact with
    navigateBackRect=[C4Shape rect: CGRectMake(0, topBarFromTop, 60, topNavBar.height)];
    navigateBackRect.fillColor=navigationColor; //this color has an alpha of 0
    navigateBackRect.lineWidth=0;
    [self.canvas addShape:navigateBackRect];
    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:navigateBackRect andRunMethod:@"navigateBack"];

    //--------------------------------------------------
    //RIGHT
    //--------------------------------------------------
    //close icon
    closeButtonImage=iconClose;
    closeButtonImage.width= 25;
    closeButtonImage.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.width-18, topNavBar.center.y);
    //closeButtonImage.zPosition=2;
    [self.canvas addImage:closeButtonImage];

    //invisible rect to interact with
    closeRect=[C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(self.canvas.width-35, topBarFromTop, 35, topNavBar.height)];
    closeRect.fillColor=navigationColor; //this color has an alpha of 0
    closeRect.lineWidth=0;
   // closeRect.zPosition=3;
    [self.canvas addShape:closeRect];
    [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:closeRect andRunMethod:@"goToAlphabetsView"];
}
```

It's executed directly from the main workspace like this

```
takePhoto= [TakePhoto new];
    takePhoto.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    takePhoto.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [takePhoto transferVariables:1 topBarFromTop:TopBarFromTopDefault topBarHeight:TopNavBarHeightDefault bottomBarHeight:BottomBarHeightDefault navBarColor:navBarColorDefault navigationColor:navigationColorDefault typeColor:typeColorDefault fatFont:fatFontDefault normalFont:normalFontDefault iconTakePhoto:iconTakePhoto iconClose:iconClose iconBack:iconBack];
    [takePhoto setup];

    [self.canvas addSubview:takePhoto.canvas];
```

in the TakePhoto subclass the  transferVariables function is really just to be able to use the global variables in the subclass. It looks like this:

```
-(void)transferVariables:(int)number topBarFromTop:(float)TopBarFromTopDefault topBarHeight:(float)TopNavBarHeightDefault bottomBarHeight:(float)BottomBarHeightDefault navBarColor:(UIColor*)navBarColorDefault navigationColor:(UIColor*)navigationColorDefault typeColor:(UIColor*)typeColorDefault fatFont:(C4Font*)fatFontDefault normalFont:(C4Font*)normalFontDefault iconTakePhoto:(C4Image*)iconTakePhotoDefault iconClose:(C4Image*)iconCloseDefault iconBack:(C4Image*)iconBackDefault{
    //nav bar heights
    topBarFromTop=TopBarFromTopDefault;
    topBarHeight=TopNavBarHeightDefault;
    bottomBarHeight=BottomBarHeightDefault;
    //colors
    navBarColor=navBarColorDefault;
    navigationColor=navigationColorDefault;
    typeColor=typeColorDefault;
    //fonts
    fatFont=fatFontDefault;
    normalFont=normalFontDefault;
    //icons
    iconTakePhoto=iconTakePhotoDefault;
    iconClose=iconCloseDefault;
    backButtonImage=iconBackDefault;

}
```

and the setup-function of the TakePhoto subclass looks like this (3 different views at the moment)

```
-(void)setup {
    //setup all the default variables
    //>colors
    navBarColorDefault=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.96875 green:0.96875 blue:0.96875 alpha:1];
    navigationColorDefault=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
    buttonColorDefault= [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8984275 green:0.8984275 blue:0.8984275 alpha:1];
    typeColorDefault=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.19921875 green:0.19921875 blue:0.19921875 alpha:1];
    overlayColorDefault=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.19921875 green:0.19921875 blue:0.19921875 alpha:0.5];
    highlightColorDefault=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.757 green:0.964 blue:0.617 alpha:0.5];

    //>nav bar heights
    TopBarFromTopDefault=   20.558;
    TopNavBarHeightDefault= 44.0;
    BottomBarHeightDefault= 49;

    //>type/fonts
    fatFontDefault=     [C4Font fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17];
    normalFontDefault=  [C4Font fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17];

    //>icons
    iconTakePhoto=  [C4Image imageNamed:@"icon_TakePhoto.png"];
    iconClose=      [C4Image imageNamed:@"icon_Close.png"];
    iconBack=       [C4Image imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"];
    iconOk=         [C4Image imageNamed:@"icon_OK.png"];
    iconSettings=   [C4Image imageNamed:@"icon_Settings.png"];


    id)createViews{
    //TakePhoto
    takePhoto= [TakePhoto new];
    takePhoto.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    takePhoto.canvas.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [takePhoto transferVariables:1 topBarFromTop:TopBarFromTopDefault topBarHeight:TopNavBarHeightDefault bottomBarHeight:BottomBarHeightDefault navBarColor:navBarColorDefault navigationColor:navigationColorDefault typeColor:typeColorDefault fatFont:fatFontDefault normalFont:normalFontDefault iconTakePhoto:iconTakePhoto iconClose:iconClose iconBack:iconBack];
    [takePhoto setup];

    [self.canvas addSubview:takePhoto.canvas];

    //CropPhoto
    cropPhoto=[CropPhoto new];
    cropPhoto.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    cropPhoto.canvas.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cropPhoto transferVariables:1 topBarFroTop:TopBarFromTopDefault topBarHeight:TopNavBarHeightDefault bottomBarHeight:BottomBarHeightDefault navBarColor:navBarColorDefault navigationColor:navigationColorDefault typeColor:typeColorDefault overlayColor:overlayColorDefault fatFont:fatFontDefault normalFont:normalFontDefault iconClose:iconClose iconBack:iconBack iconOk:iconOk];
    [self.canvas addSubview:cropPhoto.canvas];
    cropPhoto.canvas.hidden= YES;

    //AssignPhoto
    assignLetter=[AssignLetter new];
    assignLetter.canvas.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);
    assignLetter.canvas.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [assignLetter transferVariables:1 topBarFroTop:TopBarFromTopDefault topBarHeight:TopNavBarHeightDefault bottomBarHeight:BottomBarHeightDefault navBarColor:navBarColorDefault navigationColor:navigationColorDefault typeColor:typeColorDefault highlightColor:highlightColorDefault fatFont:fatFontDefault normalFont:normalFontDefault iconClose:iconClose iconBack:iconBack iconOk:iconOk iconSettings:iconSettings];
    [assignLetter setup];

    [self.canvas addSubview:assignLetter.canvas ];
    assignLetter.canvas.hidden=YES;

    //the methods to listen for from all other canvasses
    [self listenFor:@"goToTakePhoto" andRunMethod:@"goToTakePhoto"];
    [self listenFor:@"goToCropPhoto" andRunMethod:@"goToCropPhoto"];
    [self listenFor:@"goToAssignPhoto" andRunMethod:@"goToAssignPhoto"];

}
```

The main problem is that the 2 images don't appear. 
I have experimented setting their zPosition to 10, 50 and 100, but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Please post the code anyway as well as information about when and where this code is executed. It is a lot easier to help you out when there is something concrete to discuss.

Comment: added the code just now

Comment: Posting code in this case is very, very useful. If the same code run twice produces different results then it is definitely worth looking at. You may want to look at this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345477/how-to-bring-a-subview-to-the-front-when-you-tap-it

Comment: thanks Adam. I'm hiding and unhiding the views when I'm changing from one view to the next...
also: In the occasion where it always works right is when I'm running this setup code only when unhiding the view it refers to (which basically was just a try and shouldn't be like that always; it would mean that I'd have to remove everything from the views once I'm leaving them, and then run the setup-function again... which would make it more complicated than needed)

Comment: what does the transferVariables:topBarFromTop:topBarHeight:... look like. Also, what do you mean it is run directly from the main workspace? Surely it run from a method?

Comment: maybe it's easiest to look at the full code? it's here:
https://github.com/susemiessner/Urban-Alphabets/tree/master/urbanAlphabetsII