# bounds overlays other ui elements

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a transparent navbar on top of a view frame that is set to a video player,  when I set a UI element like this for example:

Code:

```
 player.view.frame = self.gplayer.bounds
```

The nav bar disappears. I tried setting a z-index using code but still the video player covers the nav bar. How could I make the navigation bar on top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bring a subview to the front when you tap it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345477/how-to-bring-a-subview-to-the-front-when-you-tap-it)

Comment: I dont want it when tapped, I dont understand why setting a view with . bounds, hides other UIViews...

Comment: If you don't want it when tapped, then put the code elsewhere.  The question @picciano linked shows you the exact code you need to use.  It's up to you to figure out where to put that code.

Comment: after messing around it worked, but the navigation bar is not clickable..